# Within a for loop how to append index value to the end of the dataframe name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want writing a 'for' loop using Python script (pandas dataframe), and would like to append the index value to the end of dataframe name to differentiate each of them, how can I do it?

For example, I have a dataframe `df` with column `value` to be 1~5; and would like to split the dataset into 5 pieces, each has `value` to be '1' / '2'/ '3'/ '4'/ '5'.

I've tried the following which seems to have syntax error. How can I change it? thanks

```
for i in range(1, 5):
   df_f'{i}' = df.loc[df['value'] == i]
```

Note:
I'd like the desired dataframe name to be `df_1. df_2, df_3, df_4, df_5`

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to generate variable names at runtime; use a list or dictionary instead.

```py
df_parts = {i: df.loc[df['value'] == i] for i in range(1, 6)}
```

A more concise version that handles all unique values of `value` instead of just 1 through 5:

```
df_parts = dict(list(df.groupby('value')))
```

You can then access each part as `df_parts[1]`, `df_parts[2]`, etc.

Comment: I added a more concise version that I just discovered; feel free to revert my edit if you don't want it in :)

Comment: @richardec I accept your addition, but `DataFrame.groupby` will raise a KeyError in this case as it expects the column name. I fixed the code example you added

Comment: Oops! Yeah, that's a typo from my own experiments. :)

Answer (score 2):

As [@hbgoddard pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71610592/17242583), it's bad practice to generate variable names dynamically (at least in production code). However, if you really want to do it, edit `globals()` like so:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
   globals()[f'df_{i}'] = df.loc[df['value'] == i]
```